# Issue with OpenGL demo - fine with NVidia, issues on AMD

Tags: performance, opengl, gpu, nvidia, amd-processor

No, this isn't another rant question about NVidia vs AMD; I'm genuinely interested in having my demo running well with both vendors. I've tested my code with four configurations:

1. MacBook Pro (NVidia GT650M) - fine
2. Desktop with CentOS 6.5 (Nvidia Quadro FX) - fine
3. Desktop with Windows 7 64 bit (AMD HD7950 with Catalyst 14.4) - slow
4. Desktop with Fedora 19 (AMD HD7950 with catalyst 14.4) - slow

3 and 4 are actually the same machine. The code is not highly optimized but it's not doing anything too complex either: I have a grid (which I render using GL_POINTS), a line that represents the path found by A* and a moving agent. The grid has about 10k elements, if I remove that the demo runs better, but still not perfectly.

I guess it's a driver issue, as on 3 and 4 it seems it's running with software rendering; I profiled the code on Windows with CodeXL and a frame take ~400ms and seems to be using mostly the CPU rather than the GPU.

As final information, I'm using GLEW and GLFW for cross-platform development. The full code is available here: https://bitbucket.org/theWatchmen/behaviour-trees

Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: It's difficult to help with a program being "slow". For all we know your "3,4" machine could be 10 times slower than the others. Also, I don't think a lot of people have time to download your whole source code and analyze it. Have you tried using a profiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original answer posted here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/659012-issue-with-opengl-demo-using-catalyst-drivers-linux-and-windows/#entry5168395

It seems that for this particular card GL_POINTS are emulated in software and that's causing the demo to slow down. I will change the grid to triangles to make sure it runs smoothly on all cards.